# Translate Dataframe Columns in Python using "google_trans_new" library

Tags: python, dataframe, google-translate

I want to translate the column "name" of my df, I have the following line

```
 data1['name']=data1['name'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
```

But I get the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Example of my df:

```
      number    name 
0       1      Αλέκος Καραβίτης
1       2      Νίκος Τζουγάνος
2       3      $IMEON
3       4      鄒森
4       5      黃國隆
```

Comment: Which library is `translator.translate` ? -- is it `!pip install googletrans` ?

Comment: @Mich Heng , I am using:                                                                                                                          from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prerequisites to install “**pip install google-trans-new**“ (Please refer [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/) for additional information):

- Python should be >=3.6
- requests : “pip install requests“
- six : “pip install six“

Then change the function from:

`data1['name']=data1['name'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)`

To:

`data1['name']=data1['name'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x,lang_tgt='en'))`

Because, “**dest**” keyword is not supported in the “**google-trans-new**” library. It’s supported only in the “**googletrans**” library. So, you should use “**lang_tgt**” instead of “**dest**” when using the “**google-trans-new**” library. Please refer [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/) for additional information.

Try below Script:

```
# coding: utf-8
import pandas as pd
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()
data1 = pd.DataFrame([
[1, 'Αλέκος Καραβίτης'],
[2, 'Νίκος Τζουγάνος'],
[3, '$IMEON'],
[4, '鄒森'],
[5, '黃國隆'] ], columns=['number', 'name'])
data1['name']=data1['name'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x,lang_tgt ='en')
print(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
# !pip install google_trans_new
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()
        
data1 = pd.DataFrame([
[1, 'Αλέκος Καραβίτης'], 
[2, 'Νίκος Τζουγάνος'], 
[3, '$IMEON'], 
[4, '鄒森'], 
[5, '黃國隆'] ], columns=['number', 'name'])

data1['name'] = data1['name'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(str(x)))
```

Output DataFrame

```
    number  name
0   1       Alekos Karavitis
1   2       Nikos Tzouganos
2   3       $IMEON
3   4       Zou Sen
4   5       Huang Guolong
```

Comment: I keep getting: AttributeError: Object 'NoneType' has no attribute 'group'
, copy your lines as is, will it be a library error?

Comment: your DataFrame might be defined differently, may need to force `x` to be a string using `str(x)`, I've updated my code